# Is Neo4j Suitable for Large Scale-free Network?

Tags: neo4j

I know Neo4j works well on large graphs, under assumption of nodes are generally equally distributed. However, in most cases, graphs in the real world follow a [scale-free](http://mathinsight.org/scale_free_network) degree distribution. My question is, if relationship types and node labels are the same respectively, are there any ways to remain speedy when querying through nodes with really high degree, like 100k neighbor nodes?